# API for responsive design view option in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there any way I can switch on Firefox's native responsive design view? Following is the screenshot after starting responsive design view

I already have an xul based addon which has another functionality but I want to start responsive design view from inside that. Also I would want to operate this(touch view and size) from my addon. I couldn't find any API for it in the docs, does it have one?

[image]

Comment: Seems like the answer is "not yet": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible.

```
var mytmp = {};
Cu.import("resource:///modules/devtools/responsivedesign.jsm", mytmp);
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
mytmp.ResponsiveUIManager.toggle(win, win.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0]);
```

set win to the `DOMWindow` meaning the chrome window, that the tab you want to toggle to responsive view

there are `on` and `off` functions avilable. here are all the functions available in `ResponsiveUIManager`:

[image]

details on functions: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/devtools/responsivedesign/responsivedesign.jsm#20

Comment: great I am able to add presets and acces it from my addon but how do I select an item. How do I event trigger or select an item in the dropdown?

Comment: Can you ask with more detail and post it in a topic.